# How to use ojdbc6.jar with Oracle 19c?

Tags: oracle, ojdbc, oracle19c

We have a legacy application, currently using ojdbc6.jar which cannot be upgraded now. However we want to upgrade to Oracle 19c. **Can we use ojdbc6.jar with Oracle 19c?**
If the answer is no, then can we set compatible to 11.2.0 to be able to use ojdbc6.jar?

Comment: ojdbc6 is dedicated for Java 6, which is out of support since 2013. Are you sure you can not use higher version of JDBC driver? Also ojdb6 drivers were shipped with Oracle database 12c. So you can also get ojdbc6.jar file compatible with 12c - supporting safer password encryption.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you can use older drivers for newer databases. You just can not use the newer features of the newer database. If the driver is really old, the dba can change the sqlnet.ora on the server to allow connections from older versions.

For example: `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=11` allows a client from version 11 to connect to the databases.

Better is to make sure the app is upgraded for support of the latest LTS release. In this case that would be 19c. Allowing older versions to connect can have security considerations.

In the [jdbc Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html) you will find a lot of information.